# Run Jenkins jobs in parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 3 different jobs (Build, Undeploy and Deploy), which want to execute Build and Undeploy in parallel and after that Deploy.

From search got to know that Build Flow Plugin got deprecated.

Please suggest a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Jenkins file with the below format:-

```
pipeline {
    stages {
    agent  { node { label 'master' } }
    stage('Build/Undeploy') {
            parallel {

                 stage('Build') {

                    agent { node { label 'Build' } }

                    steps {
                        script {
                            //Call your build script
                        }
                    }
                }

                stage('Undeploy') {

                    agent { node { label 'Undeploy' } }

                    steps {
                        script {
                            //Call your undeploy script
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    stage('Deploy'){

            agent { node { label 'Deploy' } }

            steps {
                script {
                    //Call your deploy script
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It cannot find `stages` for me.  I get this error Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, ...

Comment: Edited the answer